# hoverintent function with a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following hoverIntent function

```
$(".samplePepleCon").hover(function() 
    {
        var getId           =   $(this).attr('id');             
        var getCompleteID   =   'DataInside_'+getId;                        
        $(this).find(".presTips").delay(800).fadeIn(1000);


        }, function() 
        {
            $(this).find(".presTips").fadeOut("fast");
        }

    );
```

I want the function() to be executed after a delay/pause of maybe 500ms.. Please help

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for the [hoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html).

Comment: r6 released at last!! :) compatible with jquery-1.5.1 hurray!!